# Displaying multiple tables in one grid view in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, sqldataadapter

I am trying to load data from a database into a single `DataTable` and display it in a `DataGridView`. When running the code it gives me the exception `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'`

**Code**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\matricsneo\Desktop\New SAD\Villanueva\Villanueva\VillanuevaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter SDA1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M101", CON);
    SDA1.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M102", CON);
    SDA2.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA3 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M103", CON);
    SDA3.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA4 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M104", CON);
    SDA4.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA5 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M105", CON);
    SDA5.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA6 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M106", CON);
    SDA6.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA7 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M107", CON);
    SDA7.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA8 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M108", CON);
    SDA8.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA9 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M109", CON);
    SDA9.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA10 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M110", CON);
    SDA10.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA11 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M111", CON);
    SDA11.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA12 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M112", CON);
    SDA12.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA13 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M113", CON);
    SDA13.Fill(DT);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA14 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FROM * M114", CON);
    SDA14.Fill(DT);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

check your `SELECT` strings - those should be `SELECT * FROM TABLE` instead of `SELECT FROM * TABLE`